# Get current keyboard state without notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a main view controller with a text field close to the bottom of the screen. When the keyboard is shown, the text field moves up - no problem.

This main view controller sometimes adds a child view controller to show a popup above the text field. When the keyboard is not shown, the popup is close to the bottom of the screen, and when the keyboard is shown, the popup moves up - again, no problem.

To move my views up and down when the keyboard is shown or hidden, I'm using the standard approach: register a listener for `keyboardWillChangeFrame` notifications and update the layout based on the keyboard's frame. This works great as long as I can register a notification listener **before** the keyboard is shown.

My problem is that sometimes, I add the child controller for the popup when the keyboard is already visible. This means I can only register the notification listener **after** the keyboard is already visible. When that happens, the popup controller does not know that the keyboard is already visible, and fails to update its layout accordingly.

---

(There are of course many possible workarounds for this, e.g.

- Initialise the child controller with the known current keyboard frame, as used by the parent controller
- Create a singleton keyboard service that always runs, and so always knows the current keyboard frame

In my code, I prefer not to use singletons, and I have a simple keyboard listener service class that I add to each view controller that needs to handle keyboard changes; my workaround there is to have a static variable in this service that tracks the current keyboard frame. This works, but it's code smell.)

---

What I would like to know, though, is whether iOS provides us with a way to simply get the **current** state of the keyboard, without needing to listen for updates.

Using notifications puts the responsibility on me to have an internal model of the keyboard state, and keep it in sync with the actual state. This is good for responding to changes, but does not give me confidence that my modeled state is always accurate -- if I miss a notification, it goes out of sync. It would be strange if there was no way to simply check the actual state.

Comment: You have the keyboard frame already, so apply it on initial state of the child view if keyboard is already presented.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Yes, that's what I referred to in one of my possible workarounds. But then the responsibility is still on me to make sure I have caught the most recent update notification, and then propagate that through to the child. What I'm asking is whether there is a way to just get the current keyboard frame from the OS without having to listen for updates.